# Use GpsStatus every few seconds to sample some data

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to use `GpsStatus` and the `getSatellites()` function in my application to sample the data every 5 seconds.  I don't seem to understand how to initialize the `GpsStatus` though.  Can someone point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get GpsStatus by a listener

```
mlocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(your listener);
```

or call `getGpsStatus (GpsStatus status)`

Retrieves information about the current status of the GPS engine. This should only be called from the onGpsStatusChanged(int) callback to ensure that the data is copied atomically. The caller may either pass in a GpsStatus object to set with the latest status information, or pass null to create a new GpsStatus object.

Comment: Do I have to use a listener?  I don't want to listen to only when it changes location or something of the sort.  Just want to query every few seconds.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I got it to work :) At least it stopped crashing.